# Is the gelatinous ice cube familiar from the "D&D Celebration 2020" event official?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, dnd-adventurers-league

During the [D&D Celebration 2020](https://dnd.wizards.com/dndcelebration) event, a new option for a familiar was revealed in the form of the image below:

[image: D&D Celebration 2020 - Gelatinous Ice Cube Legacy Award]

I assumed it was official material because it was produced directly by a Wizards of the Coast event, though it does not appear in the the latest book (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*).

Is there any official word on if the material from D&D Celebration 2020 is legal in Adventurers League games and/or ordinary games, or is it essentially homebrew?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### It is Adventurers League-eligible for Season 10 and legacy characters.

[This September 2020 tweet by the D&D Adventurers League account](https://twitter.com/DnD_AdvLeague/status/1307790891558469632) states that the Celebration legacy awards are eligible for use with Season 10 and Legacy Characters:

> “Legacy Awards” have been spotted in the wild, during D&D Celebration!
> They’re cute and cool! But we realize the name itself is confusing and
> that will be addressed soon.
>
> If you found any, each cert is available for a season 10 or Legacy
> player character. Your choice!

#### For other games, ask your DM.

For other games, obviously, ask your DM. The oblex spawn is significantly more powerful than all of the usual options for *find familiar*. It is not normally a valid familiar option, as this certificate is not official D&D 5e rules content.